# Why is my navigation bar picture not moving properly?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm currently trying to make a Navigation bar for my website and it works just fine! but right now I'm stuck with this annoying picture that can't properly move.

Problem: 
I want the navigation picture just a few pixels away from the side of the page but when I use `padding-left` I also move the navigation section but I want this to be centerd and the picture to be a few pixels from the left. Hope anybody could help me

```css
body {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 0 0
 font: arial;
 }

nav {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #595959;
 color: #ffffff;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0;

  }

nav > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 25px 0 50px;
    }

nav > ul> li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-family: Roboto;
      }

nav > ul> li > a:hover {
  color: #c1c1c1
     }

nav > .logo > img {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 0 0 25px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
 <head>
  <title>Branco - Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
  <nav>
   <div class="logo"> 
    <img src="http://ikbenbranco.nl/assets/icon.png" height="60px"> 


   </div>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

 </body>

</html>
```

Thanks, Branco

Comment: I added the answer. Also why r u using such complex selectors. Just give them the right class. It's much easier. Take a look at BEM naming convention for css classes, [here](http://getbem.com/)

Comment: I will! thanks, I just started coding so I hope this will help me.

Comment: Your welcome! If this answer solved ur problem, would u mind accepting and/or upvoting the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in this case u have to position it absolutely if u don't want it to affect the other elements in the nav bar.

here's the css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: arial;
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #595959;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px 0 50px;
}

nav > ul> li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Roboto;
               }

nav > ul> li > a:hover {
        color: #c1c1c1
                    }

nav > .logo > img {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your img styles for this. Remove your float and padding lines. Add a position absolute. Then, also add a left and a top properties. Adjust the values as you wish the picture to be positioned. This should fix your issue.